# Change Nextcloud logo image

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, nextcloud

Is it possible to change the image on the [login screen of your Nextcloud server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcfCg.jpg)?

I'm using PHP 7, and MariaDB 10 running on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which version of Nextcloud you are running, but a Theming app is available for that purpose. Here is a link for version 15

https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/15/admin_manual/configuration_server/theming.html